# VBA BeforeDoubleClick Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am not very good at programming so i am asking for your help.
I have a excel list , which i cannot share due to legal/security reasons. But this list contains spaces/compartments which shows a summary of equipment.

My goal is when you click on a compartment/space; the rows beneath it, that contains details about the equipement, are shown. When you doubleclick it again; it hides. So it is some sort of grouping rows. But instead of doing it in excel itself, i want to do it in VBA.
But the thing is there are a lot of spaces and sometimes there can be a row added to a space/compartment. So i don't want to manually change the range of rows of a space/compartment by hand. So it needs to be dynamic.

I have written a bit of code but when i doubleclick on a cell i get the mismatch error, where the yellow arrow points at the private sub header and the "Is" of the second if statement gets highlighted.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

On Error Resume Next
Dim cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("List")

Dim myArray As Variant
'Dim numElements As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim iVal As Integer

Dim hideRows As Range
Dim FoundCell As Integer

'Array of spaces/compartments.
myArray = Array("TD OFFICE", "SHIP CONTROL CENTRE", "STUDY ROOM", "NETWORK OPERATIONS CENTRE")
'numElements = UBound(myArray) - LBound(myArray) + 1

'Disable double click editing for entire column B.
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then Cancel = True
    

For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    'Aquire the number of times a specific space/compartment occurs to know the number of rows of this space/comparment.
    iVal = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), myArray(i))
                
    'Find the first rownumber of the space/compartment.
    FoundCell = Sheets("List").Cells(1, "B").EntireColumn.Find(What:=myArray(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
                
    'Set range of rows of compartment/space (these are always grouped together).
    Set rng = Range("B" & 0 + FoundCell & ":B" & FoundCell + iVal)
    'Set the same range but with an offset of one.
    Set rng1 = Range("B" & 1 + FoundCell & ":B" & FoundCell + iVal)
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If (Not Intersect(Target, Range(rng) Is Nothing) And (Target.Count = 1)) Then
            Set hideRows = Range(rng1)
            hideRows.EntireRow.Hidden = Not hideRows.EntireRow.Hidden
        End If
    Next cell
Next i
    
    'Sample code that works with double clicking but isn't dynamic:
    'If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("B529:B530")) Is Nothing) And (Target.Count = 1) Then
    '    Set hideRows = Range("B530")
    '    hideRows.EntireRow.Hidden = Not hideRows.EntireRow.Hidden
    'End If

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One thing to note is that `Range(rng)` should be just `rng` as you've already declared it as that type.

Comment: Btw this code runs whenever any cell is double-clicked. You need a `If Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` at the start.

Comment: Brackets need moving: `If (Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing And (Target.Count = 1)) Then`

Comment: @SJR : Thank you for your reply: I have changed the ```Range(rng)``` to ```rng``` but your second comment; i implemented this but then it does nothing. Should that line be replacing this line: ```If Intersect(Target,Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then Cancel = True```?

Comment: @Rory Thank you for your reply: It worked, i don't get the error anymore. But the weird thing is that only TD Office and Study Room from my array are working. The other two are non responsive. Am i skipping values in my array in my for loop?

Comment: Have you also corrected the brackets as pointed out by Rory? Comment out the `On Error Resume Next` and you will get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: Looking more closely at your code, I don't understand it. You are only looping through the cells in the `rng` range, so why do you need to test them with `Intersect`, or test the count?

Comment: @Rory I only want the rows to collapse for lets say TD Office when the user clicks on a cell that contains TD Office. If i remove the for loop and/or the if statement all the rows of all the spaces/compartments in my array collapses when any name in the array is clicked on.

Comment: But why do you need to test if the `Target` intersects the `rng` range for every cell in that range, when neither `rng` nor `Target` has changed in that loop? The test only needs to happen once *before* the loop. And I hope you have also amended `Set hideRows = Range(rng1)` to just `Set hideRows = rng1`

Comment: @Rory Because i thaught that would mean that only TD office rows gets collapsed when TD office is clicked. But if i understand your comment correctly; i have swapped the for and if loop to this:```If (Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing And (Target.Count = 1)) Then
        For Each cell In rng.Cells
            Set hideRows = rng1
            hideRows.EntireRow.Hidden = Not hideRows.EntireRow.Hidden
        Next cell
    End If```